# Ternary operator not working in Android

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I have a simple question that boggles me. I am trying to use the ternary operator in java. I am new to Android and java. This code gives me the error:

```
amt < 0 ? lendBtn.setChecked(true) : lendBtn.setChecked(false);

"Syntax error on token "<", invalid AssignmentOperator"
```

So, I replace it with an if statement and it totally works:

```
if (amt < 0) { ... }
```

It's not a big deal but does anyone know why?

Comment: Please post the surrounding code, for context.

Comment: @Oli. Thanks but Jon already gave the answer! +1

Comment: Where is the value getting assigned to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Android. You can't use a conditional expression as a statement on its own... and the second and third operands can't be void expressions either.

You should use:

```
lendBtn.setChecked(amt < 0);
```

... which is simpler to start with.

Comment: "can't use a conditional statement on its own". Do you mean that I have to set it to something? something = true ? "yes" : "no". It looks like if I assign it to something, the error dissappears

Comment: @Yko: Yes - or use it as an argument within a method call, or something like that. That's how it's designed to be used. If you're just trying to change what method you call, either use a condition within the method arguments (as per my answer) or, when that's inappropriate, just use an `if` statement.